# RelativeLayout in ScrollView won't scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-scrollview

I'm working on my first android app and I'm trying to get everything to scroll except for the ad. I put everything except for the ad into a RelativeLayout and put that into a ScrollView. When I click on an EditText and the keyboard comes up everything in the ScrollView gets shifted up but I can't scroll.

Code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.tipcalculator.app.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="*adId*"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/tipTxt"
        android:editable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:hint="Other"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tipOthr"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tipOthr"
        android:enabled="false" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/priceTxt"
        android:editable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:hint="Price"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/splitInTxt"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/splitTxt"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:editable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/totalTxt"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/totalTxt"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="$0.00"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate Tip"
        android:id="@+id/calcBtn"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/totalTxt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/totalTxt"
        android:editable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="$0.00"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ tipOutTxt "
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ tipOutTxt " />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10%"
        android:id="@+id/tipTen"
        android:checked="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tipFtn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="15%"
        android:id="@+id/tipFtn"
        android:checked="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tipTnty"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20%"
        android:id="@+id/tipTnty"
        android:checked="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tipTxt"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tipOthr"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_above="@+id/calcBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Total"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/splitTxt"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Split"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/splitTxt"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Split"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tipTen"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/minusBtn" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/splitInTxt"
        android:text="1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:editable="true"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tipTen"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/plusBtn"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/splitInTxt"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tipTxt"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tipTxt" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/minusBtn"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/splitInTxt"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/splitInTxt" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/ tipOutTxt "
        android:editable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="$0.00"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Tip"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_above="@+id/totalTxt"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tipOthr" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What was the out put. Post screenshot

Comment: try to set  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` your activity in manifest.xml

Comment: take all value in scrollview...if you want to scroll every thing

Comment: try this, ScrollView  height should be "wrap_content"

Comment: I think you have to specify the Linear layout after scrollview and your whole layout inside the linearlayout.

Comment: Hey Born To Win how would I put my whole layout inside of a linearlayout?

Comment: @user3682017  which is the last component that should be visible on scrolling down?

Comment: @user2450263 I'm not sure I understand the question, I want everything to be scroll except for the ad

Comment: but do you have enough content for that? Also, come "id"s that are mentioned in layout parameters can't be found i.e.  
 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ tipOutTxt "
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ tipOutTxt "

Comment: There is enough content to fill the screen but not enough to need to scroll but when you click on an EditText and the keyboard comes up and the content shifts up I want to be able to scroll the content down. The ids are all there make sure you copied everything down correctly.

Comment: make sure you remove the space from the id part of your edittext, RelativeLayout doesn't recognize that id, only copying everything correctly won't help ->   android:id="@+id/ tipOutTxt "

Comment: Sorry you were right about the tipOutTxt issue I removed the space on my end if you remove them on your end it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,Wrap your relative layout within linear  layout.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adUnitId="*adId*"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/adView">

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:orientation="vertical">


        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/tipTxt"
                android:editable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hint="Other"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tipOthr"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tipOthr"
                android:enabled="false" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/priceTxt"
                android:editable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hint="Price"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/splitInTxt"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/splitTxt"
                android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
                android:editable="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/totalTxt"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/totalTxt"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="$0.00"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Calculate Tip"
                android:id="@+id/calcBtn"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_above="@+id/totalTxt"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/totalTxt"
                android:editable="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="$0.00"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ tipOutTxt "
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ tipOutTxt " />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10%"
                android:id="@+id/tipTen"
                android:checked="false"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tipFtn"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="15%"
                android:id="@+id/tipFtn"
                android:checked="false"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tipTnty"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="20%"
                android:id="@+id/tipTnty"
                android:checked="false"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tipTxt"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tipOthr"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_above="@+id/calcBtn"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:enabled="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Total"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_above="@+id/splitTxt"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Split"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/splitTxt"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Split"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:longClickable="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tipTen"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/minusBtn" />


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/splitInTxt"
                android:text="1"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:editable="true"
                android:gravity="center|right"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tipTen"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="+"
                android:id="@+id/plusBtn"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/splitInTxt"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tipTxt"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tipTxt" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="-"
                android:id="@+id/minusBtn"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/splitInTxt"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/splitInTxt" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/ tipOutTxt "
                android:editable="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="$0.00"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Tip"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_above="@+id/totalTxt"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tipOthr" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

To fix header and footer with scrollview you may refer this link http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-fixed-header-and-footer-with-scrollable-content-layout-example.html

Comment: That didn't work either. Does everything need to be in a linearlayout?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out some possible problem of `RelativeLayout` you have used in `Scrollview`.

You just need to use `RelativeLayout` like :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

There is no meaning of using   `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` and
 `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` at a same time.

Let me know in case it helps. :)

**Edit:** Set `ScollView` height to `wrap_content`.

Comment: @user3682017 The another approach I would suggest is use `layout_below` instead `layout_above`. Also check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.tipcalculator.app.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="*adId*"
        ads:adSize="BANNER" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/tipTxt"
                android:editable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hint="Other"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tipOthr"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tipOthr"
                android:enabled="false" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/priceTxt"
                android:editable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hint="Price"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/splitInTxt"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/splitTxt"
                android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
                android:editable="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/totalTxt"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/totalTxt"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="$0.00"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Calculate Tip"
                android:id="@+id/calcBtn"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_above="@+id/totalTxt"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/totalTxt"
                android:editable="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="$0.00"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ tipOutTxt "
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ tipOutTxt " />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10%"
                android:id="@+id/tipTen"
                android:checked="false"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tipFtn"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="15%"
                android:id="@+id/tipFtn"
                android:checked="false"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tipTnty"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="20%"
                android:id="@+id/tipTnty"
                android:checked="false"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tipTxt"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tipOthr"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_above="@+id/calcBtn"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:enabled="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Total"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_above="@+id/splitTxt"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Split"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/splitTxt"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Split"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:longClickable="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tipTen"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/minusBtn" />


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/splitInTxt"
                android:text="1"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:editable="true"
                android:gravity="center|right"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tipTen"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="+"
                android:id="@+id/plusBtn"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/splitInTxt"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tipTxt"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tipTxt" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="-"
                android:id="@+id/minusBtn"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/splitInTxt"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/splitInTxt" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/ tipOutTxt "
                android:editable="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="$0.00"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Tip"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_above="@+id/totalTxt"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tipOthr" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I was really hoping that one would work but it didn't. Does the orientation have to be set anywhere?